# Transfer learning needs to be from more relevant domain?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am in search of a reference paper where I can find out that transfer learning needs to be from domain specific source model rather than using generalise model i.e., imagenet

For example Source dataset satellite/drone hyper/multi spectral images of plants and target dataset of hyper/multi spectral images of plants captured using agricultural robot

As compared to

Source dataset ImageNet model and target dataset images of plants captured using agricultural robot

Comment: might better on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions as it not directly about programing.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer learning is especially interesting for the accuracy if you don't have enough data. For example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08883) compared training with and without pretraining on imagenet. They claim that after 10k images, pretraining does not give better results but still allows to train faster.
Then if you have a small dataset, your question still holds whether you should pretrain on imagenet or on another dataset. I think the answer to this question is given in the following paragraph (the references there are probably of interest to you):

> **Do we need big data?** Yes. But  a  generic  large-scale, classification-level pre-training set is not ideal if we take into account the extra effort of collecting and cleaning data—the cost of collecting ImageNet has been largely ignored,  but  the  ‘pre-training’  step  in  the  ‘pre-training  +fine-tuning’ paradigm is in fact not free when we scale out this paradigm.  If the gain of large-scale classification-level pre-training becomes exponentially diminishing [44, 30], it would be more effective to collect data in the target domain.

Therefore, you also need to consider the quality of your satellite image dataset. Since it should be closer to your data than Imagenet it is probably better.

Comment: What exactly this “ large-scale classification-level pre-training  ” means

Comment: In the paper, it refers here to imagenet. Classification-level means that different categories are associated with the picture and that somehow you are able to reuse the whole encoder part of your pre-trained network. You could also for example just reuse the low level features. For semantic segmentation tasks, you might also be able to find a pretrained network also for the decoder part.